# Google drive api folder permissions

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I have problem with google drive api v3. 
I took google example and I tried. I could read folder content but I did nothing with folder permission.

I received error 403, "Insufficient Permission".
I can't create or read all permissions for the folder.

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('client_secrets.json');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);
$client->setAccessType('offline');

if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
    $drive = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

    $folderId = '1_ip3-WUs4F6atNdElJ3KHccAV4lI0nLL';

    $optParams = array(
        'pageSize' => 100,
        'fields' => "nextPageToken, files(id,name)",
        'q' => "'".$folderId."' in parents"
        );

    $results = $drive->files->listFiles($optParams);

    if (count($results->getFiles()) != 0) {
        foreach ($results->getFiles() as $file) {
            echo "Id: " . $file->getId() . "  Name: " . $file->getName() . "<br>";
        }
    }   

} else {
    $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/oauth2callback.php';
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

//+!+!+!+!+!+!+!+!+!+! Next code doesn't WORK  !+!+!+!+!+!+!+!+!+!+!+!+!+!+!+!+!+!//

$fileId = '1UXSg5W-XIX82izGK8uEXXWPUCLcDGRa1';

$userPermission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission(array(
    'type' => 'user',
    'role' => 'reader',
    'emailAddress' => 'email@gmail.com'
    ));

$request = $drive->permissions->create($fileId, $userPermission, array('fields' => 'id'));
echo $request; 

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

It may be that wrong permissions have been set when creating the folder, even though you said you did nothing. I do not see the code for creating the folder here, just an ID, which indicates that the folder has already been created.

I suggest trying to list the permissions using [`Drive.Permissions.List`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/list) first. Particularly, look at the [`type`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions) and [`role`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions) or [`teamDrivePermissionDetails[].role`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions) properties. See the [permissions guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-permissions) on what operations each role or type can do. You can also visit this documentation on [managing sharing](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-sharing) in case you need to.

Comment: perhaps also worth looking at the scopes of the project. have you obtained sufficient project scope permission for the API to access. Consider adding 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive' to the OAUTH scope

Comment: Maybe it was a reason for problem. I have changed the scope of the project and now I have to wait couple of days for checking.